# Self-Referencing Tables (R Programming Language)

Tags: r, frame, data-manipulation

I am trying to make "self-referencing" grids using the R programming language. For instance, I made the following (non self-referencing) grid:

```
var_1 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_2 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_3 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_4 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_5 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_6 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_7 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)

frame_a <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7)
```

This works:

```
head(frame_a)
      var_1     var_2     var_3     var_4     var_5      var_6     var_7
1 11.106978  6.045635 12.059918 14.576642 6.6631061  2.4308557  4.210330
2  5.356593  9.066030 15.324603  4.170090 7.9821328  0.7412383  8.561553
3 16.971664  5.172987  6.501061  2.827789 0.5317087  6.2078346  9.151058
4  1.903000  7.183025 11.524599 12.188365 9.2445369  9.5063593  3.741548
5 11.744789 10.077375  4.740652  3.738349 6.1231457  5.3983903 -4.863340
6 14.151094  8.234436  8.203216 14.722724 9.6634154 -0.7918751 14.080428
```

Now, I am trying to make a "self referencing grid" - i.e. a grid with certain conditions. For each row within this grid:

- var_2 must always be greater than var_1
- var_4 must always be greater than var_3
- var_6 must always be greater than var_5
- var_7 must always be greater than var_6

This was my attempt to make such a grid

```
var_1 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_2 <- rnorm(1000,var_1,5)
var_3 <- rnorm(1000,8,5)
var_4 <- rnorm(1000,var_3,5)
var_5 <- rnorm(1000,6,5)
var_6 <- rnorm(1000,var_5,5)
var_7 <- rnorm(1000,var_6,5)

frame_b <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7)
```

This code worked, but the "conditions" were not respected:

```
> head(frame_b)
       var_1     var_2    var_3     var_4     var_5       var_6      var_7
1  5.9667356  1.518180 9.316051  3.192931 -1.358661 -0.05681164 -5.3893074
2  8.4478170 11.902876 9.588589 -1.220872  6.091870  9.81611979  4.9043055
3 13.6396693  8.554241 9.017625 10.840609 -4.548760  0.22775771 -5.8313070
4 13.4776003 19.735430 4.674371  2.144886  4.933787 -3.13381274 -0.5747767
5  6.3300270 -1.968539 4.413483  5.490492  4.866916  3.72772243 10.1688481
6  0.3662306 -1.633712 6.142054  7.236065 12.506673 10.17450918  7.7536291
```

For instance, in the first row: var_2 is not greater than var_1.

Can someone please show me how to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: You are randomly drawing numbers from a normal distribution. In `var_2` the mean of the normal distribution in each row will equal the value in `var_1`. As a result, (approximately) half of the numbers in `var_2` will be less than those in `var_1`.

Comment: did you mean to use `runif` instead of `rnorm`?

Comment: @ rawr: thank you for your reply! I guess I could have used "runif" instead of "rnorm". Is there a big difference?

Comment: well runif is set up exactly how you want: `(n, lower limit, upper limit)`, so you can use the result of `var_1` as the lower, provided that your upper limit > all of `var_1`

Comment: @ rawr : I tried to come up with an answer based on your logic. can you please take a look at it?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You say " I thought that writing "var_2 <- rnorm(1000,var_1,5)" will put a lower bound on "var_1"?" That's just wrong. There's no lower bound on a normal random deviate. Perhaps you should be looking at left-truncated distributions or shifted distributions that have a positive domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to post an answer based on the answer provided by @rawr:

```
var_1 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
var_2 <- runif(1000, var_1, 100)
var_3 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
var_4 <- runif(1000, var_3, 100)
var_5 <- runif(1000, 0, 100)
var_6 <- runif(1000, var_5, 100)
var_7 <- runif(1000, var_6, 100)

frame_3 <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7)


head(frame_3)
      var_1    var_2    var_3    var_4     var_5    var_6    var_7
1 16.824184 42.45956 26.68427 41.69108 66.104877 67.29392 92.26807
2  5.154861 74.42316 32.87011 73.93285  3.206936 62.48352 63.06708
3 35.263069 48.56498 34.64460 39.81641 12.816591 13.17151 72.77144
4 21.175502 27.04440 18.04221 64.40537 34.614670 65.89940 92.80989
5 17.156617 86.05252 10.88137 84.53697 86.133523 99.04071 99.55816
6 32.293821 89.77986 26.29747 49.53139 76.262548 81.88121 89.91402
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just test the results according to your metrics above to satisfy yourself that it is working or not? But overall, curious what you mean by 'self-referencing'.

Comment: @ Chris: thank you for your reply!  I will start looking into this!